# Cuando debo utilizar "arrow function" y cuando utilizar "function" en mis componentes de ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, funciones, component

tengo esta duda desde hace bastante tiempo, no se si es importante o no el diferenciar funciones de tipo flecha (arrow function) frente a las funciones normales (function) en los componentes de ReactJs, pongo por ejemplo un código muy sencillo.

Aquí utilizo "function", el clásico de javascript de toda la vida

```javascript
function Home() {
  return <div>Esto es la ventana Home </div>;
}

export default Home;
```

Y aqui utilizo las "arrow function" de ES6

```javascript
const Home = () => {
  return <div>Esto es la ventana Home </div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Ambos son el mismo componente pero declarados de distinta manera, uno utiliza "arrow function" y el otro "function".
Simplemente querría saber si esta diferencia es siquiera relevante para crear componentes o no, para así poder resolver una duda que tengo desde hace tiempo y también mejorar mi código de ReactJs.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo a todos

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Answer (score 0):

Te responderé en terminos de Javascript puro, ya que para react esto también se debería cumplir.

La principal diferencia (en mi opinión) es el `scope`, por ejemplo al utilizar `this`

Demo:

```js
const objeto = {

  NormalFunction :function(){
       console.log(this)
  },
  ArrowFunction : () => console.log(this)
};

objeto.NormalFunction();
objeto.ArrowFunction();
```

Como observarás ambas funciones son equivalentes, pero `this` referencian a cosas distintas.

Otra diferencia es el uso de `arguments`, el cual te permite tener argumentos variables en una función, esto no es posible en `arrow functions`

```js
const objeto = {

  NormalFunction :function(){
       console.log(arguments)
  },
  ArrowFunction : () => console.log(arguments)
};

objeto.NormalFunction(444,333);
objeto.ArrowFunction(4444,222);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la situación, pero comparto generalidades.

---

El primer ejemplo se conoce como **JavaScript function declaration**:

```
function Home() {
  return <div>Esto es la ventana Home </div>;
}
```

Se usa el keyword `function` y **presenta hoisting behavior**.

Puedes leer [acerca de hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) en JS pero en general nos permite escribir la declaración de una función en cualquier parte del archivo y llamar a la función antes de su declaración.

Esta sintáxis se conoce como **JavaScript function expression**:

```
const Home = () => {
  return <div>Esto es la ventana Home </div>;
};
```

Se usa `arrow function` y **no presentan hoisting behavior**, por lo que su declaración debe estar escrita en el archivo antes de su llamada.

Algunos beneficios de usar `function expression` en vez de `function declarations` en `react` pueden ser:

- function expression: no presentan hoisting behavior, por lo que no se
  pueden llamar antes de que se definan. Esto puede ser útil para
  evitar comportamientos inesperados en el árbol de componentes react.
- function expression: se pueden definir como expresiones dentro de otras funciones lo cual le da flexibilidad a la creación de componentes.
- function expression: el `this` binding se aplica automáticamente del `outter context`, aunque en react moderno casi no se usa el `this`.
- Con el tiempo function expression con arrow son más fáciles de leer
  sobre todo cuando se usan en callbacks (map, filter, reduce etc...)

Si quieres saber más estudia los conceptos de `this` context en JavaScript asi como `hoisting`.